# How do I make Django form fields only editable if they're blank?

Tags: python, html, django

The use case: It's kind of like a signup sheet. The form has 3 fields, each of which should only be editable if they were blank when the form was requested. Once the form is submitted, these fields for this specific instance of the model shouldn't be editable.

The question: How do I do this? I was thinking of using Javascript to set the fields to editable if they already have something in there, but I'm almost certain there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest way is to use javascript since it works directly within the browser.

just get the id of your fields and set disabled to true

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("myFieldId")

if (myInput.value.length != 0) {
    myInput.disabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check in the **init** function of your form and then update the field.

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
somefield = forms.Charfield()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.somefield is not "":
        self.fields['somefield'].disabled = True
```

Validation should always be done on the server-side and not rely on the client.